# How to flip a part of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to flip a part of an array, keeping the rest unchanged.
I have a function that flips and entire array, but... To use it, I have to take a part from my array, flip it with the function and paste it on its place. It's uncomfortable and not so fast. I need a method that works very fast.

Example:

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
flip(array,2,6); //Flip the part between index 2 and 6
```

After that, the array should look so:

```
{1,2,7,6,5,4,3,8,9,10}
```

Please, help, I need a really quick answer...

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: You can make a version of your flipping function that takes a pair of iterators (usually, a "begin" iterator and a "past-the-end" iterator), and operates on the range defined by those iterators; this has the benefit of allowing your function to work with any range, not just arrays.  Or, of course, use the standard library one that's already been mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to solve your problem with [std::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/?kw=reverse) function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::reverse(array + 2, array + 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Please note that I replaced indices 2 and 6 in your example with 2 and 7. This is because std::reverse reverses the elements in the range [first, last).

Answer (score 6):

There is an algorithm in the standard library exactly for this: `void reverse( BidirIt first, BidirIt last );`

Comment: @화이트케이크 Yes. Most standard algorithms work with arrays. Just remember that pointers are iterators for arrays.